# jQuery find closest ID and remove one of the class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

Hey all I am trying to figure out how to go about finding the next closest **ID** of a **DIV** that I then need to replace **one** of its class names (class="something0 something1 something2").

What I have to work with is this html:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="tips form-control searchable-select-holder-req" data-tooltip="example 1" data-val="" id="environment" name="environment" style="width: 260px; display: none;">
        <option value="1">IT</option>
        <option value="2">FRASTRUCTURE</option>
        <option value="3">blah 2</option>
        <option value="4">blah 3</option>
        <option value="5">blah 4</option>
        <option value="6">blah 5</option>
        <option value="7">blah 6</option>
        <option value="8">SPARE</option>
        <option value="9">LAB</option>
        <option value="10">STUDY</option>
    </select>
    <div tabindex="0" class="searchable-select" style="width: 260px; min-width: 260px;">
        <div class="tips searchable-select-holder searchable-select-holder-req" data-tooltip="example 1" data-tag="environment"></div>
        <div class="searchable-select-dropdown">
            <span>Search:</span> 
            <input type="text" class="searchable-select-input" style="width: 250px; max-width: 185px; background-color: rgb(254, 231, 231);" />
            <div class="searchable-scroll has-next">
                <div class="searchable-has-privious searchable-select-hide">...</div>
                <div class="searchable-select-items mCustomScrollbar _mCS_2" style="font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace;">
                    <div id="mCSB_2" class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-bodyScroll mCSB_vertical mCSB_inside" style="max-height: 185px;" tabindex="0">
                        <div id="mCSB_2_container" class="mCSB_container" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0;" dir="ltr">
                          <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value=""></div>
                          <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="1">IT</div>
                          <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="2">FRASTRUCTURE</div>
                          <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="3">blah 2</div>
                          <div class="searchable-select-item selected" data-value="4">blah 3</div>
                          <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="5">blah 4</div>
                          <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="6">blah 5</div>
                          <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="7">blah 6</div>
                          <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="8">SPARE</div>
                          <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="9">LAB</div>
                          <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="10">STUDY</div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="mCSB_2_scrollbar_vertical" class="mCSB_scrollTools mCSB_2_scrollbar mCS-bodyScroll mCSB_scrollTools_vertical mCSB_scrollTools_onDrag_expand" style="display: block;">
                            <div class="mCSB_draggerContainer">
                                <div id="mCSB_2_dragger_vertical" class="mCSB_dragger" style="position: absolute; min-height: 30px; top: 0px; display: block; height: 104px; max-height: 175px;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
                                    <div class="mCSB_dragger_bar" style="line-height: 30px;"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mCSB_draggerRail"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="searchable-has-next">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am currently at the **data-tag="enviroment"** part of the code to change the **inner text** which I can do without issue. Now from there I need to find the **next/closest** div with **ID** of **mCSB_2_container** and then find the **DIV** within that has a class of **selected** and **remove it** and place it on the **first** div item (which here would be a blank value).

This is my current JS that I am using to get to the **** part:

```
$("select").each(function() {
   $('[data-tag="' + this.id + '"]').text(''); //Clears Text
   //$(this).next('#mCSB_2_container').removeClass("selected");
});
```

As you can see from the code, I've tried using **$(this).next('#mCSB_2_container').removeClass("selected");** but that doesnt seem to work since its looking for the class name **selected** within the **mCSB_2_container**.

Any help would be great to figure this out!

Comment: I don't see any `select` in your code...but you're targetting it here `$("select").each(function() {`

Comment: Updated the OP to show the select part as well.

Comment: Okay. I've added an answer for you.

Comment: How is distance relevant when using an id? It must be unique anyway, so irregardless of where it is, it should be the correct element?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find()` to find the selected class like: `$(this).next('.searchable-select').find('.selected').removeClass("selected");`. Please see the working snippet below:

```js
$("select").each(function() {
  $('[data-tag="' + this.id + '"]').text(''); //Clears Text
  $(this).next('.searchable-select').find('.selected').removeClass("selected");
  $(this).next('.searchable-select').find('.searchable-select-item:first-child').addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <select class="tips form-control searchable-select-holder-req" data-tooltip="example 1" data-val="" id="environment" name="environment" style="width: 260px;">
        <option value="1">IT</option>
        <option value="2">INFRASTRUCTURE</option>
        <option value="3">blah</option>
        <option value="4">blah</option>
        <option value="5">blah</option>
        <option value="6">blah</option>
        <option value="7">blah</option>
        <option value="8">SPARE</option>
        <option value="9">LAB</option>
        <option value="10">STUDY</option>
    </select>
  <div tabindex="0" class="searchable-select" style="width: 260px; min-width: 260px;">
    <div class="tips searchable-select-holder searchable-select-holder-req" data-tooltip="example 1" data-tag="environment"></div>
    <div class="searchable-select-dropdown">
      <span>Search:</span>
      <input type="text" class="searchable-select-input" style="width: 250px; max-width: 185px; background-color: rgb(254, 231, 231);" />
      <div class="searchable-scroll has-next">
        <div class="searchable-has-privious searchable-select-hide">...</div>
        <div class="searchable-select-items mCustomScrollbar _mCS_2" style="font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace;">
          <div id="mCSB_2" class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-bodyScroll mCSB_vertical mCSB_inside" style="max-height: 185px;" tabindex="0">
            <div id="mCSB_2_container" class="mCSB_container" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0;" dir="ltr">
              <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="">first item</div>
              <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="1">IT</div>
              <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="2">FRASTRUCTURE</div>
              <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="3">blah 2</div>
              <div class="searchable-select-item selected" data-value="4">blah 3</div>
              <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="5">blah 4</div>
              <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="6">blah 5</div>
              <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="7">blah 6</div>
              <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="8">SPARE</div>
              <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="9">LAB</div>
              <div class="searchable-select-item" data-value="10">STUDY</div>
            </div>
            <div id="mCSB_2_scrollbar_vertical" class="mCSB_scrollTools mCSB_2_scrollbar mCS-bodyScroll mCSB_scrollTools_vertical mCSB_scrollTools_onDrag_expand" style="display: block;">
              <div class="mCSB_draggerContainer">
                <div id="mCSB_2_dragger_vertical" class="mCSB_dragger" style="position: absolute; min-height: 30px; top: 0px; display: block; height: 104px; max-height: 175px;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
                  <div class="mCSB_dragger_bar" style="line-height: 30px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="mCSB_draggerRail"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="searchable-has-next">...</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about changing the **first** **searchable-select-item** to **selected** now?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. See my updated answer. Beware...that the first item from your code has no text so do an inspect to see the class added there.

Comment: Yep that did it, lonut. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you can do this.

```js
$('.container').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $(this).next().attr('id');
    $('.container').remove(x);
});
```

```html
<a class="container" id="1" href="#">One</a>
<a class="container" id="2" href="#">Two</a>
<a class="container" id="3" href="#">Three</a>
```